# How to prepare a .aar for an .apk, without building a .apk? (Processing out ${applicationI})

Tags: android, gradle, android-library, package-name

We're building an SDK for Unity for Android, and while they *do* accept .aar files, it's not a full `gradle` build system, it's their own custom implementation, and one of the differences to gradle is it doesn't replace `${applicationId}` references in any `AndroidManifest.xml`s.

There is a bug report sent in to `Unity 3D`, but we provide an SDK for Unity, which will be using plenty of .aar libraries, so even if they fix it, we support back to some of the early 5.x versions of it, so we need to provide a solution for those versions.

I've looked through some of the output of a regular Android build, but can't really get my head around what's happening at those points, and when gradle swaps out `${applicationId}` for the package name of the app.

Currently the solution we've resorted to is unzipping the .aar files, and doing a manual search and replace, and including them as Unity plugin `library folders`, which does work, but we'd much prefer a more elegant solution, like running,

```
gradle buildFor com.example.myapp
```

Which would produce a .aar with all references to `${applicationId}` in AndroidManifests (as well as anywhere else it might be used in a normal gradle build) replaced with `com.example.myapp`, but any attempt to do *anything* at all with applicationId with gradle an Android library seems to be in vain, and I haven't been able to find much information about this process online.

Comment: `com.android.library` builds AARs and `com.android.application` builds APKs. You build one or the other, not both.

Comment: I don't think you understand the question. Where have I said I want to build both?  I'm trying to find out if I can run some sort of pre processor, or any preparation for an Android Library project, to use in another build system, that we don't have control over.